# How to measure total boottime for linux kernel on intel rangeley board

Tags: linux, intel

I am working on intel rangeley board. I want to measure the total time taken to boot the linux kernel. Is there any possible and proven way to achieve this on intel board?

Comment: What distro are you using, Ubuntu ie, come with some nice profiling graphs.

Comment: There's bootchart (http://www.bootchart.org/), but I think that starts after init starts.

Comment: Thanks Brian Cain, is there any way to get the full boot time

Comment: Hi xvan, i am currently using centos

Answer (score 2):

Try using `rdtsc`.  According to the Intel insn ref manual:

> The processor monotonically increments the time-stamp counter MSR
>   every clock cycle and **resets it to 0 whenever the processor is reset.**
>   See “Time Stamp Counter” in Chapter 17 of the Intel® 64 and IA-32
>   Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3B, for specific
>   details of the time stamp counter behavior.

(see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to manuals)

Normally the TSC is only used for relative measurements between two points in time, or as a timesource.  The absolute value is apparently meaningful.  It ticks at the CPU's rated clock speed, regardless of the power-saving clock speed it's actually running at.

You might need to make sure you read the TSC from the boot CPU on a multicore system.  The other cores might not have started their TSCs until Linux sent them an inter-processor interrupt to start them up.  Linux might sync their TSCs to the boot CPU's TSC, since `gettimeofday()` does use the TSC.  IDK, I'm just writing down stuff I'd be sure to check on if I wanted to do this myself.

You may need to take precautions to avoid having the kernel modify the TSC when using it as a timesource.  Probably via a boot option that forces Linux to use a different timesource.